# how do you treat hives on a pitt bull?

Tags: dogs

I want to know how you treat hives on your pet dog? possible bee pollen!! Looks like small pumps in one area.

Comment: Can you post pictures?

Comment: All health related issues for your pets should have your veterinarian involved. At least a phone call to check if the issue requires an office visit.

Answer (score 1):

You can give your dog Benadryl at the recommended dose for your dog's size but I recommend calling your vet first to make sure it won't interfere with any other medicine he is on. If you do decide to go this route, you give them 1mg per pound they weigh. Also, I highly recommend getting the children's liquid Benadryl as it is much easier to measure out. This will likely make your dog sleepy till it wears off. Source: http://www.petmd.com/dog/care/can-i-give-my-dog-benadryl-and-if-so-how-much

Answer (score 1):

You should always consult your Veterinarian before giving your dog any medication. However, Benadryl is a very common over the counter medication used for dogs to treat hives or bee stings. Dosages should be given at 1mg per 1lb. You will find most tablets come in 25mg so you should cut them accordingly or use children's Benadryl. It is very important that you are using Benadryl with the active ingredient diphenhydramine only. Source: [Beloved Bark](https://belovedbark.com/giving-dogs-benadryl/)